# Timer и TimerTask при запросе Get

Tags: java, http

Есть класс который заходит на сайт методом `get`. Мне нужно что бы в случае ответа сервера `!=200` метод повторился через какое-то установленное время, например через 5 минут. данный класс я сделал `TimerTask` переопределил его метод `run` что бы он вызывал сам себя.
Из стороннего класса я создаю экземпляр `GetTask`, вызываю по ссылочной переменной метод `doGet()`если все ок и сервер возвращает `200` то работаем дальше, если нет то в условии проверки вызываю `Timer` - но тут что-то пошло не так:
 - метод работает не останавливаясь;
 - прорабатывает полностью весь метод не смотря на мой `if` с начала и до конца
 - условие про количество таймеров не срабатывает
Подскажите что я делаю не так. и можно ли вообще так делать?

```
    public class GetTask extends TimerTask {

  Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void doGet() {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        ValueCharset valueCharset = new ValueCharset();
        if (debug) {
            int a = 0;
            statusLine = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusLine != 200) {
                a++;

                timer.schedule(new GetTask(charset, header, genClient,
                        rootDirectory), 5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
                if (a > 3) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                response.close();
                genClient.setClient(client);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    doGet();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прокомментирую в вашем коде:

```
public class GetTask extends TimerTask {
    // Вы создаете отдельный экземпляр Timer в каждом экземпляре вашего задания
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void doGet() {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        ValueCharset valueCharset = new ValueCharset();
        if (debug) {
            // Локальная переменная a, всегда равна здесь нулю
            int a = 0;
            statusLine = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusLine != 200) {
                a++; // теперь она всегда равна 1

                // Timer.schedule(TimerTask, int, int) запускает задание
                //   (ваш новый GetTask) на периодическое исполнение
                //   (через 5 секунд будет выполняться каждые 10 секунд)
                timer.schedule(new GetTask(charset, header, genClient,
                        rootDirectory), 5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
                if (a > 3) {
                    // никогда не выполнится, т.к. a == 1
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Если вылетит IOException, повторного выполнения может не быть
        //   хотя может быть вы так это и задумали.
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                response.close();
                genClient.setClient(client);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    doGet();
}
```

Код создает бесконечное количество `Timer` которые бесконечно будут периодически выполнять `GetTask.doGet()`.

Вам нужно сделать `a` полем класса. Дальше можно или:

a) Ставить задание в очередь один раз: через `timer.schedule( new GetTask(..), 0, 5*1000 )` (вызвать задание сразу и каждые 5 * 1000 миллисекунд) и потом в теле `doGet()` вызывать `this.cancel()` (отменяет это задание), когда `a > 3`;

```
class PeriodicGetTask extends TimerTask {
    private int a = 0;

    private void doGet() {
        a++;
        System.out.println( "Что-то делаем..." );
        int statusLine = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 200 : 500;
        if (statusLine == 200) {
            System.out.println( "Успех!" );
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            System.out.println( "Что-то идет не так, возможно мы повторим попытку...");
            if (a > 3) {
                System.out.println( "... не повторим, превышено число попыток.");
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doGet();
    }
}
```

b) Создавать новое задание рекурсивно, передавая в конструкторе количество предыдущих попыток. Если число попыток превышено, или задание выполнено успешно, не добавлять новое задание в таймер:

```
class RecursiveGetTask extends TimerTask {
    private int a = 0;
    private Timer timer;

    public RecursiveGetTask( int previousAttempts, Timer timer ) {
        a = previousAttempts;
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    private void doGet() {
        a++;
        System.out.println( "Что-то делаем..." );
        int statusLine = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 200 : 500;
        if (statusLine == 200) {
            System.out.println( "Успех!" );
        } else {
            System.out.println( "Что-то идет не так, возможно мы повторим попытку...");
            if (a <= 3) {
                timer.schedule( new RecursiveGetTask( a, timer ), 1000 );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "... не повторим, превышено число попыток.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doGet();
    }
}
```

Еще желательно унести всю полезную работу (включая обработку исключений и прочее) в отдельный класс, экземпляр которого сможет ответить на вопрос "требуется ли повторное выполнение?". Это позволит написать универсальный класс для повторного исполнения не сработавших задач.

Comment: спасибо большое. очень помогли. подскажите еще плиз как заставить подождать основной поток пока выполниться таймер?

Comment: В смысле, дождаться успешного/неуспешного завершения вашего задания? Если делать на коленке, то я бы отдал в GetTask экземпляр `latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(1)`, после финиша в `doGet()` вызвал на этом экземпляре `countDown()`, а в основном потоке ждал бы вызовом метода `latch.await()`. Не на коленке - посмотрел бы [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry). Вообще, если вы останавливаете поток до завершения задачи, проще обойтись без таймеров и в цикле сделать.